# Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80

Tags: apache, servidor

Alguns dias atrás quando troquei a versão do *PHP* do servidor e fui reiniciar o *apache*, então me mostrou o erro:

```
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80

(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
```

Para resolver, fiz o seguinte:

rodei o comando: `netstat -tlpn | grep 80`

Me mostrou o seguinte:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80     0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN      1355/nginx      
tcp6       0      0 :::80          :::*              LISTEN      1355/nginx
```

Então finalizei o processo com o comando: `kill 1355`, reiniciei o *apache* e aí ficou rodando apenas o *tcp6*.

Porém hoje fui acessar o *site* e vi que estava mostrando: *ERRO 502 BAD GATEWAY* . Fui reiniciar o *apache* pra ver se resolveria e me mostrou o mesmo erro que mencionei antes. Realizei o mesmo processo e funcinou.

Queria saber o por que está acontecendo esse tipo de erro e se tem alguma forma de resolver definitivamente.

Answer (score 0):

Caso a ajuda anterior não funcione. No meu caso eu já havia instalado o apache pelo xampp, desinstalei mas alguns processos ainda estavam executando e impedindo que o apache subisse. 
Execute esse comando para ver os processos que estão executando na porta 80: sudo ss -plnt sport eq :80 (rode com o sudo!)
depois veja os processos e termine eles com o kill numero_do_processo

Answer (score 0):

Existe um post no próprio stackoverflow que pode te ajudar .

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160339/starting-apache-fails-could-not-bind-to-address-0-0-0-080

No meu mac eu usei os seguintes comandos.

```
sudo apachectl -k start
sudo apachectl -k stop
sudo apachectl -k start
```

Assim deu certo.

Caso não der para você da uma olhada nesse link que certamente pode te ajudar.